# Could not build with cordova CLI, EPERM Error

Tags: cordova

I know similar questions have been asked already but none seem to fix my issue.
When I write the command cordova build, I get an EPERM Error.
I have run the cmd.exe as administrator and checked for the authorizations in the folder but nothing seems to be working.

Here is what the CLI returns :

```
C:\VisualStudioOnline\WK_GANET_MOBILEAPP\Mobile\www\www>cordova build
Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\VisualStudioOnline\WK_GANET_MOBILEAPP\Mobile\www\platforms\android\assets\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\whitelist.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:500:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1099:15)
    at C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\prepare.js:123:16
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\prepare.js:98:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.handlePrepare (C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\prepare.js:77:24)
    at C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:105:21
    at Array.map (native)
```

Any thoughts on the matter?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on different platforms, while developing with cordova in **Visual Studio**. The problem is that some folders in the projekt are **read-only**. Starting Visual-Studio as an Admin somtimes fix it.

**Solution 1 inside Visual Studio:**
If your projekt is an Team-Foundation projekt you have to check out the **whole projekt**.

> In Solution Explorer or in Source Control Explorer, select the files that you want to edit, open their shortcut menu, and choose Check Out for Edit (MSDN).

**Solution 2:** You can right click on your platforms folder on windows and click on the readonly checkbox to remove the property. You can see the path inside your CMD.

> C:\VisualStudioOnline\WK_GANET_MOBILEAPP\Mobile\www\platforms\android\assets\www\plugins